# Connecting 4 MySql tables for real estates

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I have 4 MySql tables with real estates connected together and I am working on the formu to filter the results by (price, space, rooms etc.)
Could somebody help me to find the good way to do that? I am not beginner with MySql but clean solution for 4 tables it's a bit too much for my skills. Thank you guys. https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6cUh.jpg

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
`immos_companies`.id AS company,
`immos_companies_objects`.id AS object,
`immos_companies_objects_floors`.id AS floor,
`immos_companies_objects_floors_flats`.id AS flat 
FROM 
`immos_companies`,
`immos_companies_objects`,
`immos_companies_objects_floors`,
`immos_companies_objects_floors_flats`
WHERE 
`immos_companies_objects_floors_flats`.pid = `immos_companies_objects_floors`.id 
AND
`immos_companies_objects`.pid = `immos_companies`.id 
AND 
`immos_companies`.added IS NOT NULL
AND
`immos_companies_objects`.added IS NOT NULL
AND
`immos_companies_objects_floors`.added IS NOT NULL
AND
`immos_companies_objects_floors_flats`.added IS NOT NULL
```